# Finding the remainder of the sum of the maximum numbers in different lists in Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
K, M = list(map(int, input().split()))
S = 0
for _ in range(K):
    S += max(list(map(int, input().split()))) ** 2
print(S % M)
```

This exercise is about finding remainder by summing every power 2 of the maximum numbers in K lists: S then print the remainder of S modulus by M.

Input example:

7 867

7 6429964 4173738 9941618 2744666 5392018 5813128 9452095

7 6517823 4135421 6418713 9924958 9370532 7940650 2027017

7 1506500 3460933 1550284 3679489 4538773 5216621 5645660

7 7443563 5181142 8804416 8726696 5358847 7155276 4433125

7 2230555 3920370 7851992 1176871 610460 309961 3921536

7 8518829 8639441 3373630 5036651 5291213 2308694 7477960

7 7178097 249343 9504976 8684596 6226627 1055259 4880436

Output:

866

The problem in this example is my code returns: 31 instead of correct number 866. Does anyone have suggestions for returning the expected answer?

Comment: Could you explain how the `input()` functions are used? Maybe include the series of numbers in your code exactly how it would be used?

I don't understand your first line of code: `K, M = list(map(int, input().split()))` - This would result in a `ValueError` unless your list has a length of 2.

Comment: This seems like a problem from one of those online problem solving sites like hackerrank etc. so can you please add link to the original question? Just to check, the case of misunderstanding the question.

Comment: [here it is](https://hackerrank-challenge-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/8696-maximize-it-English?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1471019009&Signature=FF9avAu%2Fu6eeFzNiFoENfZOwt7c%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3Dmaximize-it-English.pdf&response-content-type=application%2Fpdf) @Lafexlos

Comment: @AMagoon when using the input().split() method, users input a series of the number like 5 2 3 4 1, it returns a list of string ['5', '2', '3', '4', '1']. To convert that list into integer list, I use map() function.

Comment: It seems like you misunderstood the q. You need to maximize the remainder(S%M), not just get max of every list then take remainder. That example kind of misleading in that regard sadly.

Comment: Consider the case, you have four lists of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and your M = 10. If you take max of each list and do the math you'll get 0((25*4 )%10) but if you use three 5s and one 2 you'll get 9((25*3 + 4)%10). I am on mobile so I couldn't explain in details but hope you understood what's being asked now.

Comment: So I have to find the numbers which will make S % M largest, right?

Comment: @DũngTrịnhTrung The link you provided doesn't work. It looks like it's stored somewhere only you can access it. I'm getting an access denied response.

Comment: @AMagoon I think I understand what this problem means now